# .htaccess with 2 parameters messing up css, js, images paths

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was working with URLs on my webpage but I can't solve issue for URLs with 2 parameters.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/?$ index.php?strona=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/?$ index.php?strona=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

URLs seem fine except that when my current URL has 2 parameters (for example I'm on *http://example.com/subpage/5* whole webpage is broken (stylesheets, navigation etc) because .htaccess changed all links to:

```
(for example navigation):
http://example.com/subpage_with_2_parameters/home
instead of
http://example.com/home
```

Pages with one parameter (example: *http://example.com/contact*) work fine.

Only solution (which is horrible) I have on mind are absolute links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not the only one dealing with this problem of css, js, images paths getting messed up after implementing *so-called* pretty URLs. I am seeing these problems being reported on SO almost every day.

You can solve this problem in 3 ways:

1. Best solution is to use absolute paths for images, css and js files i.e. start your path with `/` or `http://`
2. Another option is to use base href tag in HTML head section like this:

   `<base href="http://www.example.com/">`
3. 3rd option is via mod_rewrite

Put these lines **above** your other RewriteLine in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+\.(?:js|css|jpe?g|png|gif))$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not your rewrite rules which are breaking your stylesheets, but your actual HTML. The same thing would happen if you had an actual directory called `foo` and placed `index.php` in there.

If you write `<a href="home">Home</a>`, that link is relative to *the current directory* (in URL-space) so on a page with a URL like `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz` it links to `http://example.com/foo/bar/home`.

What you want instead is for the link to be relative to the *root of your domain*; for that, you need a leading slash: `<a href="/home">Home</a>`

The only reason this seemed to work before is that all your URLs were in the root directory, so "current directory" and "root of domain" were the same thing.