# Remove Filename from url with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, web, seo

I want to remove file name and extension from url, i have a directory (Blogs) and two files in it (Main_blogs.php) and (Blog.php)

**localhost/SikandarIqbal.net/blogs/**

when i open Main_blog.php in directory "Blogs" i get the above url which i was able to get with this htaccess file :

```
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine on
# prevent direct access to PHP files
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404,L]
# rewrite requests for a directory to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/Main_blogs.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0/Main_blogs.php [L]
```

and when i open a specific blog from Main_blog.php the url becomes

**localhost/Sikandariqbal.net/Blogs/Blog.php/My-Blog-name**

what i really want is to be like something

**localhost/Sikandariqbal.net/Blogs/My-Blog-name**

Remove the filename Blog.php between /Blogs/ and /My-Blog-name

please help! 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional rule for this:

```
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine on

# prevent direct access to PHP files
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(Blogs)/page/(\d+)?$ $1/?pn=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

# rewrite requests for a Blogs/Blog.php/<url>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(Blogs)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/Blog.php/$2 [L,NC]

# rewrite requests for a directory to Main_blogs.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/Main_blogs.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0/Main_blogs.php [L]
```

Comment: its not working
Error
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: ok its working if i manually change the url and adjust it to the setting did in htaccess but when i open through anchor it adds tht filename automatically,, right now this is the anchor 
 <a href="Blog.php/<?php echo $new_name ?>">Open</a>
what changes it needs to be work fine.

Comment: the htaccess u gave me working fine if i add url like mysite/blogs/my-blog-name... but with anchor it wont

Comment: now url becomes 
http://localhost/sikandariqbal.net/Blogs/Blogs/blog-name
and wont work..

Comment: i used this <a href="<?php echo $new_name ?>">GO</a>
i have no clue how its working now.

Comment: Yes that will also work as relative URL since your current path also has `Blogs/`, but it is safer to use `<a href="/Blogs/<?php echo $new_name ?>">Open</a>`

Comment: when i use /Blogs/ it becomes 
localhost/Blogs/Blog-name and wont work.

Comment: i have added pagination to my blogs page now i have url like this when i navigate in different pages 
localhost/sikandariqbal.net/Blogs/?pn=2
 what i want is it to be something like 
localhost/sikandariqbal.net/Blogs/page/2 
really looking forward for ur help @anubhava

Comment: I've updated answer but please don't add new requirements using comments, better you post a new question for additional problems.

Comment: the code is working but css is not, why is that?
and notes taken.

Comment: [See this answer to fix broken css/js/images](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16849521/548225)